# What is an intuitive way to see $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}x+\frac{d}{dx}\cos^{-1}x=0$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Without calculation, explain why $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}x+\frac{d}{dx}\cos^{-1}x=0$?

Comment: $\sin^{-1}x +\cos^{-1}x=\pi/2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because $\sin^{-1} x + \cos^{-1} x$ is constant, i.e. it does not change as $x$ changes.

Draw a right triangle.  The two acute angles are the arcsine and the arccosine of some number.  Their sum is $\pi/2$, or, if you like, $90^\circ$.  As the angles change, the sum remains $90^\circ$.  Since the quantity does not change as $x$ changes, its derivative with respect to $x$ is $0$.